# How to point a perforce workspace to a project that is synchronized across two machines?

Tags: windows, linux, perforce, workspace

I have an eclipse synchronized project where I do the work on my Windows machine and then synchronize and compile it on the linux build server.  However, the Windows workspace is connected to perforce and the linux one is not.  The problem is that when Eclipse synchronizes the two, the permissions get messed up on the linux side so that I cannot execute certain shell scripts that usually execute during the build.  The workaround that I have would be to somehow chmod all the *.sh files before executing a build, but I would much rather have perforce know about both places (that way I could also commit from either the linux side or the windows side).  For performance reasons, I couldn't run eclipse on the remote build server so this was the only solution I found.  Also, when I tried setting up a second workspace for the linux side, it gave me errors saying "could not clobber X".  I think the main problem is that I'm dealing with some sort of permissions issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have found the answer.  According to the perforce [documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html):

> > By default, you can only use a workspace on the machine that is specified by the Host: field. If you want to use the same client workspace on multiple machines with different platforms, delete the Host: entry and set the AltRoots: field in the client specification. You can specify a maximum of two alternate client workspace roots. The locations must be visible from all machines that will be using them, for example through NFS or Samba mounts.
> >     Perforce compares the current working directory against the main Root: first, and then against the two AltRoots: if specified. The first root to match the current working directory is used. If no roots match, the main root is used.
> >     Note
> >     If you are using a Windows directory in any of your client roots, specify the Windows directory as your main client Root: and specify your other workspace root directories in the AltRoots: field.
> >     In the following example, if user bruno's current working directory is located under /usr/bruno, Perforce uses the UNIX path as his client workspace root, rather than c:\bruno_ws. This approach allows bruno to use the same client workspace specification for both UNIX and Windows development.
> >     Client: bruno_ws
> >     Owner:  bruno
> >     Description:
> >             Created by bruno.
> >     Root:   c:\bruno_ws
> >     AltRoots:
> >             /usr/bruno/
> >     To find out which workspace root is in effect, issue the p4 info command and check the Client root: field.
> >     If you edit text files in the same workspace from different platforms, ensure that the editors and settings you use preserve the line endings. For details about line-endings in cross-platform settings, refer to the Perforce System Administrator's Guide.

Answer (score 2):

You could have two workspaces, one for each machine. When you've done the work on the Windows machine, you could [shelve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html) the changes, and then [unshelve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/unshelve.html) them on the Linux machine and do the build there.

Comment: Unfortunately, our version of perforce is too old to support shelving.  I tried doing that once, and when I unshelved my changes, they were all corrupted.

Comment: How does the synchronization happen now? Does the Linux machine just grab all the files from the Windows machine? Is this something you have control over?

Comment: Shelving is a great solution for this. Perhaps you could upgrade your server?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to set up alternate roots in Perforce:

1. Created a workspace in Windows
2. Set the current client (workspace) with "p4 set P4CLIENT=workspace_name", I used Windows+Cygwin to do this
3. Removed the "Host" from this client (workspace) "p4 client -o | grep -v Host: | p4 client -i" I used Windows+Cygwin to do this
4. In Linux added the alternate root in P4V, don't use ~, use the absolute path, I didn't test environment variables
5. Switched to the workspace in P4V
6. Got the latest revision in P4V, and checked the "Force" option

References:

1. http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3412
2. [Override host to null in perforce client creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521159/override-host-to-null-in-perforce-client-creation)
3. https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/client.html
4. sqenixs's answer here