# Override host to null in perforce client creation

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I am creating a perforce client using

```
p4 client -o -t old_client new_client
```

I want to remove the Host variable from the perforce spec. I tried to override the Host value using

```
p4 -H '' client -o -t old_client new_client
```

but still the perforce client is getting created taking the `Host` info from `p4 info` command. Any idea how I can remove Host parameter. I am doing this programatically. So, opening the client file and removing `Host` wont work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the Host field from the workspace spec, do:

```
p4 client -o -t old_client new_client | grep -v Host: | p4 client -i
```

That is, simply grep out the Host field before submitting the client form back to the server.